# Combine two lists for web scraping project

Tags: python, list, web-scraping

I have two lists: one is a basic list, with some being "new line" symbols (\n), and the other is a list of lists.

I would like to combine these, inserting the elements from the second list into the first list where \n appears so that the end result looks like this:

```
first_list = ['a','b','c',\n, 'd','e','f','g','h',\n]

second_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

## combine the two lists to get:

```
combined_list = ['a','b','c',1,2,3,'d','e','f','g','h',4,5,6].
```

I'm not quite sure why, but all of the \n's in the first list in my example have the same index position. Thus, when I try to loop through both lists to first find the position of the first \n and insert [1,2,3] at that point, it ends up inserting [1,2,3] at all positions where \n appears. I tried to simplify the problem here to make it easier to communicate, but the original problem comes from a web scraping project I am working on to retrieve information from Linkedin, with the elements in these lists being profile attributes for Linkedin users. Perhaps that could help to explain why the \n's all have the same index position?

Any help with how to properly combine these lists in the above way/explanations for why the \n's have the same index position would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if I can provide any additional details. Thanks.

Comment: Your code block contains some invalid Python. If you don't mind, please wrap strings in quotes.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're asking. Are `list1` and `list2` the inputs, with `list3` the desired output? Whether or not that's the case, you'll also need to share the code you tried that didn't work, and what the incorrect result was.

Comment: You can write a one liner like this `list3 = list(filter(lambda x: x != '\n', list1)) + [x for sublist in list2 for x in sublist]`

Comment: @Kaymal that worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you mentioned there were some indexing issues with the \n values, but hopefully this sets you on the right track..it works for the simplified example data you provided (re-formatted to be proper considering the letters are not variables)

```
l1 = ['a','b','c','\n','d','e','f','g','h','\n']
l2 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]

l3 = []
n_count = 0

for i,l in zip(range(len(l1)),l1):
    if l != '\n':
        l3.append(l)
    elif l == '\n':
        l3.extend(l2[n_count])
        n_count += 1


print(l3)

['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3, 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 4, 5, 6]
```

if you can figure out the indexing issue this might help you with minor modifications

Answer (score 0):

I assume that List1 and/or List2 can be continued.

The number of lists in List2 needs to be higher or equal than '\n's in List1.

```py
List1 = ['a','b','c', '\n', 'd','e','f','g','h', '\n']
List2 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
# wanted = [a,b,c,1,2,3,d,e,f,g,h,4,5,6]

list3 = []
counter = 0
for val in List1:
    if val == '\n':
        [list3.append(elem) for elem in List2[counter]]
        counter += 1
    else:
        list3.append(val)
print(list3)
['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3, 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 4, 5, 6]
```